# RAM usage rises after printing dataframe copy in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, ram

Whenever I slice a data frame with `loc` `iloc` `filter`, etc. it increases my RAM usage, whats happening? why this does not just print the slice?
If it is saving it in Out like it's suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67356512/memory-leak-in-python-jupyter-notebook), how can I avoid that behavior?

I'm using jupyter notebook in vscode, `pandas==1.5.2`.

Comment: without additional details: doesn't sound like a problem?

Comment: Any `Out[...]` lines are stored in memory.

Comment: really? how did I never realised that? I've beet working with jupyter for at least three years and never had this problem when printing a dataframe slice with those methods

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few steps you can take to decrease your ram usage while using `jupyter-notebok`:

- Write functions for processing and only return the processed variable. This is the most important part, it will save a lot of hassle specially while using `pandas`
- Clear garbage

```
import gc 
gc.collect()
```

- Clear cache

```
import ctypes
libc = ctypes.CDLL("libc.so.6") # clearing cache 
libc.malloc_trim(0)
```

Comment: garbage collect does not work in jupyter

Comment: thanks for the advise, but i'm exploring a dataset, i can't write functions at this point. also those libraries do not solve neither adress the issue

Comment: in that case, use a smaller sample of the dataset. see this https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html